# How do CNNs process RGB images

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, computer-vision, conv-neural-network

In a Convolutional Neural Network, the process of convolving is abundant.

It is known that if you take a 5x5 greyscale image (1 channel) and convolve it with a 3x3 filter (containing certain weights) you get a 3x3 feature map as a result as demonstrated by this picture: Convolutions

But what happens once you extend this notion of convolving into RGB images whereby now you have 3 channel (R,G,B) to convolve over? Well you simply add a channel to your filter proportional to the # of channel in your original image right? Lets say we did, the process of convolving with an RGB would like the following: a 6x6x3 RGB image convolved with a 3x3x3 filter. This apparently results in a 4x4x1 rather than what one would expect 4x4x3.

My question is why is this so?

If you surf the internet for visualizations of feature maps, they return with some form of colorful low & high level features. Are those visualizations of the kernels themselves or the feature maps? Either way, they all have color which means they must have more than 1 channel no?

Answer (score 0):

Look at pytorch's [`Conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Conv2d.html#torch.nn.Conv2d) you'll notice that the size of the kernel is affected not only by its spatial width and height (3x3 in your question), but also by the number of *input* channels and *output* channels.
So, if you have an input RGB image (= 3 input channels) and a filter of size 3x3x3 (=a *single* output channel, for 3 input channels and spatial width/height = 3), then your output would indeed be 4x4x1.
You can visualize this filter since you can interpret it as a tiny 3x3 RGB image.
Visualizing features/filters that are deeper in the network is not at all trivial, and the images you see are usually the result of optimization processes designed to "uncover" the filters.  [this page](https://distill.pub/2017/feature-visualization/) gives an overview of some intricate methods for feature visualization.

Comment: I have heard that the output of this process of convolution introduces a feature map that does NOT in fact hold color-based values but simply based the weights your kernal has used to convolve with. So what I am trying to say is that the output can simply be visualized using a heatmap no?

Answer (score 0):

Well, color images are :3 channels by definition, as well you can see a color picture as a stack of 3 matrices of values , so 2 Red and blue can be set up to zero,, also you should check about the sparcity of a network...